Deploying a flask app on cpanel but there is no python app setup option using apache to proxy to nginx
I already deployed python applications on cpanel before but that when i had the python app setup option but rn i was given a server with no such option as the image shows
enter image description here
so i tried deploying directly through configuring the apache conf file  which is generated by cpanel but when using mod_wsgi it crashes the main domain website
atm i am trying to make apache proxy to nginx accessing the application using the server ip and the port nginx running on makes it work with no problems but trying to access it via the apache proxy conf i made doesnt work
#apache proxy conf
ProxyPass /portal http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /portal http://localhost:8080/

#nginx listening on port 8080
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name localhost;
    ...
}

when i use the curl command it with the specified domain in apache it actually works but in the browser it gives page not found error
i tried asking my hosting provider to include the python app option but it seems customer support are not good at IT support. does anyone know whats the problem?
ps.
i did add the required proxy modules in the apache conf file and the server is running on amalinux os there is a main domain and i want to deploy my app on a subdomain.
